# Application to gather mouse usage statistics

Tags: windows, mouse, statistics

Any application available to gather and analyze stats about mouse usage.

For e.g.: Mouse movement speed, number of productive and unproductive clicks, etc. The more the analysis available the better.

I have look at anti-mousing its the closest that I have found to my usage unfortunately the stats reset every time you close the program. I need a program to gather stats for long term analysis.

P.S: Any similar program for keyboard usage too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want **[Application Usage Statistics.](https://github.com/UsageStats/UsageStats)**

This application generates statistics on the usage of **keyboard and mouse**. It's freeware.

[image]

Features:

Mouse :

1. Record mouse travel distance and number of mouse clicks
2. Record mouse wheel scrolling
3. Clicks per hour
4. Mouse track map (draws the mouse cursor track)
5. Drag track map (draws lines when mouse is down)
6. Click map (draws a point at each click)
7. Double click map (draws a point at each double-click)
8. Active mouse time (total time when the mouse has been in use)

Keyboard :

1. Record keyboard strokes
2. Keystrokes per hour
3. Key frequency
4. Active keyboard time

Applications :

1. Record time per application
2. Report mouse and keyboard usage per application

Interruptions :

1. Records interruptions (no mouse/keyboard activity for a given time)
2. Interruptions per hour

**Reports :**

- Automatically stored as .txt and .png

Comment: that's very cool, needed to measure average mouse movement speed. Like you know to distinguish a slow user from a fast user

Comment: Its very buggy and it doesn't do applications well I'm still testing it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like [Mousotron](http://www.blacksunsoftware.com/mousotron.html).

[image]

Some Features

> - view distance in Metric system or English system
> - Animated background (turn on/off option)
> - Support for all monitor sizes
> - Stay-on-Top option
> - Runs on startup
> - **Saves distance history**
> - Easy Setup
> - display number of keystrokes
> - display number of mouseclicks (left, right, middle and double)
> - configurable display options
> - Time logging and display in several modes
> - Scroll Wheel Support
> - Upload your scores online
> - Multiple Languages : English, French, German and lots more New in
>     this version
> - cursor speed added

Answer (score 1):

**[WhatPulse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatPulse)** is a key counting program  which monitors the number of keystrokes and mouseclicks, and more recently the distance the mouse moves, that a user makes over a period of time.

[Official website of WhatPulse](http://whatpulse.org/) says:

> - Discover and track your keyboard and mouse usage.
> - Track your usage history.
> - Free and multi-platform.

Comment: Nice application, but we need to register to use it and it seems to have a hard time running without crashing (always crashes after 12 hours - posted on two different PC with Windows 7 and Windows 7 SP1).

Comment: have a program track my keyboard and send it to a another company's server ... hmmm sorry no